# Where should stuff be done in an ASP.NET page?

Tags: asp.net, page-lifecycle

I'm very new to ASP.NET and, after beating my head on [a few problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180443/how-to-programmatically-create-and-use-a-list-od-checkboxes-from-asp-net), I'm wondering if I'm doing things wrong (I've got a bad habit of doing that). I'm interested in learning about how ASP.NET operates.

My question is: Where can I find documentation to guide me in deciding where to do what processing?

As a few specific examples (I'm interested in answers to these but I'd rather be pointed at a resource that gives more general answers):

- What processing should I do in `Page_Load`?
- What processing should I do with the `Load` event?
- What *can* I do in `Page_Unload`?
- What order do things get done in?
- When is each event fired?
- What is the page life-cycle?

---

edit: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924422/net-request-lifecycle-confusion/937103#937103) might also be of use to some people.

Comment: The ASP.Net page lifecycle claims another victim.

Comment: What? Am I now doomed to become addicted or something? `<g/>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ASP.net page lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

The first thing you need to learn to be able to understand the the questions you just asked is: PAGE LIFE CYCLE. It is a bitch sometimes, especially the ViewState part.

•What processing should I do in Page_Load?

•What processing should I do with the Load event? = **Page_load**

•What can I do in Page_Unload? **Clean up**

•What order do things get done in? **PAGE LIFE CYCLE**

•When is each event fired? **PAGE LIFE CYCLE**

•What is the page life-cycle? [image]

**Edit:** Image source: http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20051227.asp

More info: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/PageLifeCycle.aspx

Comment: Do you have link to where that image came from? It's not going to be much good without some explanation.

Comment: Not as much of a bitch as wiring up event handlers to dynamically created objects ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, that link doesn't provide much context.

Comment: see the link in runtime's answer

Answer (score 5):

The links posted by various folks are very helpful indeed - the ASP.NET page life cycle really isn't always easy to grok and master!

On nugget of advice - I would recommend preferring the overridden methods vs. the "magically" attached methods, e.g. prefer the

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
```

over the

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Why? Simple: in the overridden methods, you can specify yourself if and when the base method will be called:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{ 
    base.OnLoad(e);
    // your stuff
}
```

or:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{ 
    // your stuff
    base.OnLoad(e);
}
```

or even:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{ 
    // some of your stuff
    base.OnLoad(e);
    // the rest of your stuff
}
```

or even:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{ 
    // your stuff
    // not call the base.OnLoad at all
}
```

You don't have that flexibility in the Page_Load() version.

Marc

Answer (score 4):

Here are some good links to get you started.  Understanding *how* the ASP.NET life-cycle fits together is critical to understanding how your code will interact with it.

[ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx):

> When an ASP.NET page runs, the page
>   goes through a life cycle in which it
>   performs a series of processing steps.
>   These include initialization,
>   instantiating controls, restoring and
>   maintaining state, running event
>   handler code, and rendering. It is
>   important for you to understand the
>   page life cycle so that you can write
>   code at the appropriate life-cycle
>   stage for the effect you intend.
>   Additionally, if you develop custom
>   controls, you must be familiar with
>   the page life cycle in order to
>   correctly initialize controls,
>   populate control properties with
>   view-state data, and run any control
>   behavior code. (The life cycle of a
>   control is based on the page life
>   cycle, but the page raises more events
>   for a control than are available for
>   an ASP.NET page alone.)

[The ASP.NET Page Life Cycle](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/020102.htm):

> When a page request is sent to the Web
>   server, whether through a submission
>   or location change, the page is run
>   through a series of events during its
>   creation and disposal. When we try to
>   build ASP.NET pages and this execution
>   cycle is not taken into account, we
>   can cause a lot of headaches for
>   ourselves. However, when used and
>   manipulated correctly, a page's
>   execution cycle can be an effective
>   and powerful tool. Many developers are
>   realizing that understanding what
>   happens and when it happens is crucial
>   to effectively writing ASP.NET pages
>   or user controls. So let's examine in
>   detail the ten events of an ASP.NET
>   page, from creation to disposal. We
>   will also see how to tap into these
>   events to implant our own custom code.

Comment: Both of those links look useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would definitely recommend you reading this:

http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/howaspnetworks/howaspnetworks.asp

If you're new to asp.net you'll have some trouble getting all of that, but really, I have yet to find such a detailed document on the topic comming from ms documentation or any ms employee blog.

I did it the hard way and followed every path I could using disassembled code but that guy really took the time to write it.

Comment: That a cool read and worth the time. +1 However, it stops just below the point I'm interested in learning about (it's *to* low level)

Answer (score -1):

Basically try and do it in `Page_Load` and if that doesn't work, try it in either `Page_Init` or `Page_Render`. Normally one of them works :) That's the scientific approach.

Comment: To the person who voted me down - it was meant to be a joke, silly!

Comment: And as a joke it shouldn't be near the top of the answers.