# ASP.NET User Control - Accessing the main Page object in AddedControl

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

How can I access the main page object in the AddedControl event of a user control?

I am trying to run the line of code
        ScriptManager oSCM = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);
in that event, but it returns null, even if there is a scriptmanager on the parent page.  In the OnInit event in the WUC that same line of code returns the scriptmanger object, but not in the addcontrol.  Am I using the page object wrongly in that event - do I need to access it differently?

Cheers

MH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take a look at the ASP.NET Page Life Cycle, see this post on SO and my answer to it:

[Where should stuff be done in an ASP.NET page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190011/where-should-stuff-be-done-in-an-asp-net-page/1190033#1190033)

Comment: Thanks for that, but I think I need a bit more detailed view of the early part.  I have done a lot of debugging (having overridden every event I can see in the user control, so I can see what's firing when) and I can the flow going through the AddParsedSubObject and AddedControl stages - it seems to get through them ok for the update panel as it loads a control I inserted after the panel, but then it hits the unload events as the error is raised, I need to know where the "No script manager present" error is occuring, and whether the page is instantiated by that point.....

Comment: ....so I can then use the ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page) method to see if there is the SCM instantiated, and add it if not.  The problem is that at the AddedControl stage (as I think I mentioned) the page is still null so I need to do it after then.  I suspect that I may be in a chicken-and-egg scenario as the page maybe isn't being made available until after the "No scriptmanager" error is being raised, so I can't then test for the existence of the scriptmanager and insert one before the error kicks in.  Or is there a way of using the SCM GetCurrent method (or something similar)....

Comment: ....to check, from the user control, for the existence of a scriptmanager at this earlier stage?

Cheers

MH

Comment: That was useful information, but I have since found that this can't be done.