# When and how to initialize the ViewState?

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate

I am trying to use ViewState to store a collection, but it always get me the error:
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
I don't know when to initialize it and where? Sometimes I use:

```
if(ViewState["X"]==null) ViewState["X"] = new List<Checkitem>();
```

and I put it at the Page_Init() event, but it keeps initializing it each time to a new instance!!

When I try to write it like:

```
 if (!IsPostBack)
            ViewState["keywords"] = new List<Checkitem>();
```

It's not initialized later and shows the error mentioned above!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ViewState.Add("key", "value"); //adding value in viewstate 
    String abc = ViewState["key"].ToString(); //getting value from viewstate
```

Answer (score 1):

See this post and my answer to it, I suggest you read up on ASP.NET Page Life Cycle (the image included in the referenced post should provide some clues as where the ViewState is available:

[SO POst](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190011/where-should-stuff-be-done-in-an-asp-net-page/1190033#1190033)